# how to set values in TD tag using 2d array in a dynamically generated html table

Tags: javascript, html

Here I created 2d array and assigning the array value to TD element using nested for loop, but it doesn't generate the table. It provides me a blank web page.

```
var tbl3=document.createElement("table");
tbl3.border="1";
tbl3.setAttribute("cellpadding",25);    
var col_mt=document.createElement("td");
var row_hd=document.createElement("tr");
var mt_txt=document.createTextNode("");
col_mt.appendChild(mt_txt);             
row_hd.appendChild(col_mt);         

for(var i=1;i<=mc;i++) {
  var row_txt=document.createTextNode("M"+i);
  var col_hd=document.createElement("th");
  col_hd.appendChild(row_txt);
  row_hd.appendChild(col_hd);   
}

tbl3.appendChild(row_hd);       

for(var i=1;i<=mc;i++) {
  var row_st=document.createTextNode("M"+i);
  var col=document.createElement("th");
  var row=document.createElement("tr");
  col.appendChild(row_st);
  row.appendChild(col);

  for(var j=1;j<=mc;j++) {
    var cell=document.createElement("td");
    //var col_txt=document.createTextNode(res[i][j); <--this res[i][j] is 2D array, But it produces error
    cell.appendChild(col_txt);
    row.appendChild(cell);
  }

  tbl3.appendChild(row);
}

div3.appendChild(tbl3);
```

Answer (score 0):

`mc` is undefined (that's within the loop), define what mc is (eg what i is getting compared to), you might need to append it to the page (try document.write or $().append())

Comment: no i already initialized the 'mc' value with the html form (textbox) value. var mc=document.forms["f1"]["t1"].value;

Comment: for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
{
  for(var j=0;j<5;j++)
  {
  res[i][j]=i+j;
  }
} 
for(var i=mc-1;i>0;i--)
{
 for(var j=i-1;j=>0;j--)
 {
  res[i][j]=res[j][i];
 }
} here it does not allow to assign a[i][j] to a[j][i]

Comment: Make a JSFiddle if you want more help, as there seems to be a lot of missing information